# While google login from frontend using http.get method getting CORS policy error in angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, backend, google-signin

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&client_id=465544304857-3faafatnn26pmf2hgsjmscidels9p962.apps.googleusercontent.com:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Install [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module add the following code:

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:5000'];
const corsOptions = {
    origin (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
        }
    }
};
app.options('*', cors()); // CORS pre-flight
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

See the `whitelist` array. Add url here which you want to whitelist.

For example: add `google.com` to the array.

Comment: I have already added headers in my app.js file. It is working fine, when I am switching from 4200 to 3000 port. But when trying to logging in with google getting above error